# Nao estou a conseguir passar o vetor do subprograma para o programa,remodelado

Tags: c, dev-c++

*Faça um subprograma que tenha como parâmetros de entrada e saída: o endereço de um vetor de números inteiros e o número de elementos desse vetor. O subprograma deve eliminar do vetor todos os valores que estejam fora do intervalo entre 10 e 20, recolocando os valores dentro do vetor e ajustando o número de elementos do vetor*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int NrVector(int j);

int main(){
    int j,vector[j],z=0,h;

    printf("Introduza o nr de numeros que pretende introduzir:");
    scanf("%d", &j) ;
     h=j;

    vector[z] = NrVector(j);    
    printf("%d", NrVector(j));
            for(z=0;z<j;z++){if(10<=vector[z] && vector[z]<=20){
            printf("{%d}", vector[z]);}
            else{ h-=1;}    }

            printf("o nr de elementos: %d", h);

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    exit(1);
}
    int NrVector(int j){
    int vector[j],i=0,z=0,valor;

                for(i=0;i<j;i++){

                printf("Introduza o nr:");
                scanf("%d", &valor);
                vector[i]=valor;}

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vários erros. Tente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void NrVector(int *, int);

int main() {
    int j, y, z, h;
    printf("Introduza o nr de numeros que pretende introduzir:");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    int vector[j];
    h=j;
    NrVector(vector, j);
    for(z=0; z<h; z++) {
        if(10<=vector[z] && vector[z]<=20) {
            printf("{%d}", vector[z]);
        }
        else {
            for (y=z+1; y<h; y++)
                vector[y-1] = vector[y];
            h-=1;
        }
    }
    printf("o nr de elementos: %d\n\n", h);
    for(z=0; z<h; z++)
        printf("\t[%d]: %d", z, vector[z]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void NrVector(int * vet, int j) {
    int i=0, z=0;
    for(i=0; i<j; i++) {
        printf("Introduza o nr:");
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }       
}
```